# exporting pandas dataframe of complex numbers to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working with pandas data frame which has complex numbers as column data. I am trying to export this DataFrame to excel using DataFrame.to_excel method which throws the following error.

raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0} to Excel".format(value))

ValueError: Cannot convert (1.044574-3496.069365j) to Excel

Is there any roundabout way of doing this? My DataFrame looks like this,

```
Freq        lne_10720_15820_1-lne_10720_18229_1      lne_10720_15820_1  \                                                               
48                (1.044574-3496.069365j)         (7.576632+64.778558j)   
50                (1.049333-3355.448147j)         (7.557604+67.544162j)   
52                (1.054253-3225.613165j)         (7.656567+70.317672j)
```

Comment: Have you tried casting your variables as strings before export?

Comment: No, I was not sure if it is memory efficient, but if that is the only way, I will try it and post the the outcome.

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) there is a argument for float_format which you can set to 'string' maybe that will help.

Comment: @UlfAslak the float_format argument is used to 'format' float data types. For example float_format="%.2f" will force all float datatypes to have two digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem is to typecast your variables in the dataframe to `string` type as follows:

```
DataFrame = Dataframe.astype(str)
```

After performing this operation, the types of each variable is an `object` type and can be verified using `DataFrame.dtypes`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @UlfAslak..tried using float_format as '%f+j%f'...but that did not work.

Comment: your solution works like charm, only issue I have is the braces get transferred too to excel. I understand that's because the original DataFrame has them in it...but thanks for the solution.